# Positioning unordered list

Tags: html-lists

I'm having an issue with an unordered list. I'm making the web where I "forward" some information from an input field to the unordered list aligned vertically. All works fine if I fill all 5 lines but if I want to fill for example only top and the bottom lines - I would like to be 3 empty lines between them. But I can't make them stay like that. What I get is two lines one after another at the top. I could "force" it to happen with the ordered list but then I get those numbers which I don't want to have there. I tried to remove them with {list-style: none} but then again I come back to same where I was with unordered list. Any ideas guys?

Comment: No we don't have any ideas from what you've provided. you haven't provided any code at all or what you've already tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't think the code is necessary in this particular case as I explained the issue. As I said I found the solution with the ordered list but I'm not satisfied with numbers in front of each li. Removing them with {list-style: none} doesn't help.

Comment: If you want answers, provide code. that's how it works around here.  I'm not going to waste my time guessing which of the thousands of way you could have done this you chose

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/noo8gu9v/

Comment: how is that code not working? in what way does that demonstrate your problem? you're really not helping yourself here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f9htdeas/1/

Comment: I answered your question best I can with the info provided, but you get a downvote for refusing to fix your question.  your unformatted, barely legible paragraph is not a replacement for a well formatted question that actually demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.  I hope in the future you put more effort into your question if you want others to take time out of their day to assist you. If you fix your question, I will remove the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[make your list display as a block](https://jsfiddle.net/f9htdeas/1/) with a minimum height

```
ol {
  list-style: none
}

ol li {
  display: block;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one